# Почему не обновляется связь многие ко многим в EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Есть следующие модели

```
public class OperationItem
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Toolset> Toolsets {get;set;} = new List<Toolset>()
}

public class Toolset
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<OperationItem> Links {get;set;} = new List<OperationItem>();
}
```

между которыми настроена связь многие ко многим следующим образом

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OperationItem>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Toolsets)
    .WithMany(x => x.Links)
    .UsingEntity(
        "OperationItemToolsets",
        l => l.HasOne(typeof(Toolset)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("ToolsetId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Toolset.Id)).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction),
        r => r.HasOne(typeof(OperationItem)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("OperationItemId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(OperationItem.Id)).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction),
        j => j.HasKey("OperationItemId", "ToolsetId")
    );
```

Для изменении свойства Links реализовал следующий метод

```
NetCore.Models.Toolset UpdateToolsetLinks(NetCore.Models.Toolset original, IEnumerable<int> linksIds)
{
    original.Links.Clear();
    foreach (var id in linksIds)
    {
        var link = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries<NetCore.Models.OperationItem>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Entity.Id == id)?.Entity;
        if (link == null)
        {
            link = _context.Set<NetCore.Models.OperationItem>().Attach(new NetCore.Models.OperationItem { Id = id }).Entity;
        }
        original.Links.Add(link);
    }
    return original;
}
```

Редактирую toolset следующим образом

```
var toolset = _context.Set<Toolset>().Include(x=>x.Links).Single(x=>x.Id == Id);
toolset = UpdateToolsetLinks(toolset, updatedModel.Items);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Никаких ошибок не происходит, все проходит успешно но после этого теряется связь между Toolset и OperationItem.

приведенный мной код работал в NetFramework 4.8 и Entity Framework 6.4.4 сейчас проект переписывается под Net 7.0 и Entity Framework Core 7.0.14.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48963653/5610621), смысл сводится к тому что очистка и последующее заполнение навигационного свойства в ef core не работает, поэтому метод обновляющий навигационное свойство был переписан так что бы добавлять/удалять то чего нет

```
NetCore.Models.Toolset UpdateToolsetLinks(NetCore.Models.Toolset original, IEnumerable<int> updatedLinkIds)
{
    var linkIds = original.Links.Select(x => x.Id);

    var removed = linkIds.Except(updatedLinkIds).ToList();

    var added = updatedLinkIds.Except(linkIds).ToList();

    foreach (var linkId in removed)
    {
        var link = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries<NetCore.Models.OperationItem>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Entity.Id == linkId)?.Entity;
        if (link == null)
        {
            link = _context.Set<NetCore.Models.OperationItem>().Attach(new NetCore.Models.OperationItem { Id = linkId }).Entity;
        }
        original.Links.Remove(link);
    }

    foreach (var linkId in added)
    {
        var link = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries<NetCore.Models.OperationItem>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Entity.Id == linkId)?.Entity;
        if (link == null)
        {
            link = _context.Set<NetCore.Models.OperationItem>().Attach(new NetCore.Models.OperationItem { Id = linkId }).Entity;
        }
        original.Links.Add(link);
    }

    return original;
}
```